# Regex multiple occurrences in string line

Tags: regex, substring

I have to match some substring in this format `%variable%` defined by the user.

In the text it is possible this situation by mistake:

```
abcd`%variabl%e%`abcd`%variable%`abcd
```

A simple regex like this `%[^%]+%` matches the wrong values:

```
%variabl%
%abcd%
```

I just want to get %variable% ignoring %variabl%e% and the other invalid matches.

PS: it's possible a situation like %variable1% and %variable2% in the same line, I must match both of them.

Is there anyway to do this without increasing the complexity of the regex.

Comment: What is the expected output? What are the requirements for the pattern?

Comment: Probably you want `%[^%]+(?=%)`

Comment: I can recommend [Regex101](https://regex101.com) for you to test more easily, it also shows the explanation for your regex.

Comment: I looks like, rather than matching a pattern, you want to search for a specific set of values. Are you sure regex is the right tool for the job?

Comment: If you ask to get [`%variabl%`, `%e%`, `%abcd%`, `%variable%`](https://regex101.com/r/8ybjet/1) mind these are overlapping matches and this is a common issue in regex. What is your regex flavor? If you want to do that in Oracle, you cannot use a mere `regexp_substr` since Oracle regex engine is POSIX based and does not support lookarounds. Please tag the question with the appropriate language tag, otherwise, it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `substring` in your question, here's a non-regex approach using `indexOf()` and `substring()`

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String data = "abcd%variabl%e%abcd%variable%abcd";

        int firstIndex = data.indexOf("%");
        int nextIndex = data.indexOf("%", firstIndex + 1);

        while (nextIndex > -1) {
            System.out.println(data.substring(firstIndex, nextIndex + 1));
            firstIndex = nextIndex;
            nextIndex = data.indexOf("%", firstIndex + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
%variabl%
%e%
%abcd%
%variable%
```

### UPDATE

If you're wanting just pure regex

```
(?<=%)[^%]+%
```

This pattern will get you the same result, but without the beginning `%` from each matching result.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WPBt88/1)

and @revo pattern `%[^%]+(?=%)` will have the same result, but without the ending `%` from each matching result.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WPBt88/2)

Comment: The OP tags using substring, that could be done with Java, C#, C++, VB .NET, etc...  I just decided to use Java.

Comment: I'm refraining from downvoting, since this is actually a good answer in my opinion, but beware that it may not answer the question, if it turns out the OP is using any of the other languages you mentioned (or even Oracle, as Wiktor points out).

Comment: I mentioned Oracle since OP has posts tagged with Oracle in the history, and `substring` is a common tag used in SQL related questions when string manipulation is meant.